# How to denote the set $A$ correctly?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let be $I=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ is the set of indices. 
I have an increasing sequence of positive real numbers: $$0<a_1<a_2<\ldots <a_n.$$
**Question.** How to denote the set $A$ correctly?

My attemps are:

1. $A=\{a_i \in \mathbb{R}^+: a_i < a_{i+1}, i=1,2, \ldots,n-1\}.$
2. $A=\{a_i \in \mathbb{R}^+: a_i < a_{i+1}, i \in I\}.$
3. $A=\{a_i \in \mathbb{R}^+: a_i < a_{i+1}, i \in I\setminus\{n\}\}.$
4. $A=\{a_i \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}: a_i < a_{i+1}, i \in
       I\setminus\{n\}\}.$
5. $A=\{a_i \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}\}$ and $\forall i \in I\setminus\{n\}: a_i<a_{i+1}.$

Comment: First and third are the same, and are correct.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want the elements of the set $A$ to be?  Is $A$ just supposed to consist of these particular numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$?

Comment: @EricWofsey, I'd like to write that elements are ordered.

Answer (score 1):

If the $a_i $ are given (which is what I understand from your text), then you should simply write $A=\{a_i, i  \in I\} $
The fact that the elements are ordered is another property which stands besides.
1 and 3 are correct in terms of indices, but they mean you are considering all such sets, and since any positive real belongs to such a set, it is in fact simply $\mathbb {R}^*_+$

Answer (score 1):

Easy: **Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ be an increasing sequence of positive real numbers**. Many times explaining in words conveys equally well, and needs less expertise with LaTeX.